# Is it bad practice to make a constructor complex

Tags: php, oop, constructor

So I am making a PHP website to browse my movie collection on my LAN. It has been through several iterations and now I am thinking that object-oriented is the way to go. In the current state I have several functions that get movie information from the database. So whenever I need information for a movie I have to call a few functions to get all the info and pass that to other functions to do what I want with it.

My idea for the object-oriented version is to do all these 'getinfo' functions in the constructor. So I just create a movie object and all the info is readily available use `$movieobj->title` and so on.

I gave it a go and came up with this just to test it out:

```
class movie{
public $tite = Null;

function __construct($id, $conn){

//set title property
$sql_select = $conn->prepare("SELECT title FROM movie.title 
                              WHERE `movieID` = {$id} LIMIT 1");
$sql_select->execute();
$sql_select->bind_result($val);
$sql_select->fetch();
$this->title = $val;
}
```

}

This works how I want, being able to get the movie title using:

```
$movie = new movie(100,$db);

echo $movie->title;
```

But in practice I would have a few more similar chunks of code in the constructor to get other information for the movie.

Is this the wrong way to use the constructor? Should it be more simple and then have other methods to pull this information from the database? Having a complex constructor makes other code much simpler, but is it bad practice, or could it cause problems I am not seeing?

Comment: Yes, computation in constructor is bad practice, because it makes the code extremely hard to test. If you need to "prepare" the object, before it can be used elsewhere, then you instead should use a factory/builder to isolate all this preparation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, I personally would only use the constructor to set basic property values passed in as arguments, such as the connection, keeping the constructor code itself as simple as possible; and have all the real code in other methods, such as a fetch method (e.g. `getMovie()`) to actually do the database retrieval in your case, rather than direct access to the movie property (making that property private or protected).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that when you Google for "database query in constructor" you find that this issue - even if you emphasize complexity instead - has been asked repeatedly.

My take is that it *is* bad practice to query the database in constructors.

There is no direct cost when you look at it on a "low level", the discomfort people have is more general. Now, it's easy to disregard such non-specific objections, in practice, when you do this, you'll likely do fine, and equally well compared to separating the database query into a fetch method. In fact, you then have to write more code, an additional line to fetch the data.

What you gain in such cases is on another level than your concrete little project in front of you: you force yourself to use a certain style that on average is going to benefit you more, even if in the short term you have a (tiny) disadvantage.

The benefit is that when you get used to separating the database queries you gain flexibility and "order": If the code is changed later because you want to reload data during the lifetime of the object you have to refactor what you already wrote (including in all the places where you instantiated such an object, and if others used your code as a module they'll have to do it too), or destroy/recreate the object. If the fetch function is extra right from the start it is going to work no matter what!

So your first suggestion is okay for someone who writes their personal hobby project on a weekend once a year, if you are or want to be a professional programmer for reasons going way beyond any one particular project you should go for what is more maintainable and "orderly" long-term. Long-term means projects that are programmed quickly and "dirty" in an enterprise setting because they are supposed to be small end up 5 years later as "monsters", because during the first two years the programmers thought such short-cuts are okay because "it's just a small project".

As I see it, this is the real purpose of such conventions, to take care of what you can't see (the future).

Comment: +1, but it's best not to escalate disagreement in comments. Ignore contributions that you do not find constructive, imo. (I've asked for a mod to consider deletion).

Answer (score 1):

You could isolate the database access from the constructor. Your constructor should then be used to set properties of the class, `Movie` in this case. My Movie class would then have a signature like so `Movie($title, $director, $year, ... )`. A Movie object would represent a single row in my database. If I would be making repeated database calls, I would consider putting that in a static function of the Movie class, or as an external function which I would call only once.